# Kotlin Volley POST Request: ParseError || Value Hat of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.message

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-volley, parse-error

When posting a JSONObject to my webservices, I always get the following error:

**I/System.out: Error com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value Hat of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.message**

Always the VolleyError is displayed.

Json looks like this: {"channel1":255,"channel2":255,"channel3":0}

Code to generate JSON:

```
data class DMX(
        var channel1: Int = 0,
        var channel2: Int = 0,
        var channel3: Int = 0,
    )
val DMXValues = DMX(255, 255, 0)
val j = Gson().toJson(DMXValues)
val json = JSONObject(j)
```

My Webservice processes this one fine, with no errors.
But what's the "Value Hat"?? Didn't find anything on Google...

My code:

```
val jsonRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, json, { response ->
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    },
        {error: VolleyError ->
            println("Error $error.message")
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Didn't work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the exact json you used to get this error, basically your json string has a error(syntax error - in the source string or a duplicated key) in being converted into a JSONObject.

Sample kotlin verion of String request with post body,

```
val stringRequest: StringRequest = object : StringRequest(httpMethod, url, Response.Listener { response ->
            // on response implementation
        }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            //on error implementation
        }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                return httpHeaders ?: java.util.HashMap()
            }

            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getBody(): ByteArray {
                // return your body here
                return 'you body'
            }
        }
```

Comment: Added this. But printing out my JSON gives a valid one like given above.

Comment: Thanks, is your API reponse a JSONObject or String?                                                                    If you want to receive the result as a string don't use the JSONRequest you can go with StringRequest

Comment: It's an JSONObject POST request. So I need to post this one. Response could be String.
GET request response is String and works with 200.

Comment: Yea may I know the API response value(and its type), like to be specific in your code what is the type of 'val jsonRequest'?, in the below code,                                                      val jsonRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, json, { response ->
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    },
        {error: VolleyError ->
            println("Error $error.message")
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Didn't work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        })

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find out how to get the API response status in Volley :(

Comment: Sure could you use any REST client test tool like POSTMAN etc and see what is your response for this API call

Comment: ah yeah, this shows code 200  and the response text (string) I programmed in my API

Comment: Exactly, as mentioned since your API response is a String and not a JSONObject you can go with volleys - StringRequest instead of JSONObject

Comment: Hey, but then it's not possible to post a JSON object to the api. Or do I then have to implement a JSON object response in my API?

Comment: hi you override the getBody( method in Request<T> class) while creating a StringRequest and provide the jsonobject as a string there. You can refer this working example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579845/how-can-i-post-a-jsonobject-using-volley-and-receive-in-a-string                                                                                           Use the accepted answer.

Comment: No problem in Java, but what about Kotlin? There are no more arguments after ResponseError.

Comment: hi, it is not in the method arugument, it is done by extending the 'Request' class and overriding its methods(in our case getBody() ) by using Anonymous inner class implementation,  I have posted the example code as answer as I cant put it as a comment